# Reg socket communication issue

Tags: sockets, delphi, delphi-xe7, wifi

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing Client and Server application. I have created Server application using Delphi XE7, I'm running the server application in my Local system(Laptop which is connected to Wifi. IP: 192.168.0.4 ). And i have created Android Mobile application using Delphi XE7 firemonkey and it's IP address is 192.168.0.3. These IP address are assigned automatically. And both my Laptop and mobile are connected to Same Wifi Network. And in the firemonkey mobile application, i'm using TIdTcpClient for connecting the Server application: TCPClient.Connect. But i can not able to connect my mobile application to the server application. I'm getting exception that Connection Timeout. Previously i was using different Wifi Network. At that time i can able to connect properly. Please provide me is there any settings.

Comment: What port are you using? is it permitted through firewall? Without the code it's hard to say much more.

Comment: The port number is 2211. And that is permitted through firewall. Also if I'm running the application in my system, then it is connecting to the server app.

Comment: And if iam closing the server application and then i'm trying to connect from mobile application. Then i'm getting the error "no route to host"

Comment: To check if the server is listening at that port use (in a `cmd` window): `telnet 192.168.0.4 2211`. Also, post the code where you do the connect.

Comment: The command screen is coming as blank and in the server application is comming as it is connected.

Comment: If i'm changing the port also it is not connecting. Any wifi setting problem

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging. Perhaps some packet tracing. We can't see any code or any networking details. We can only give you broad tips, but nothing you don't already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very sorry. Windows firewall was blocking that application.